# Probability of the case when $r'\neq r$ and $r'$ is a factor $r$ in the order finding algorithm

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, shors-algorithm, order-finding

In the Order-Finding algorithm it is stated that it might be that $s$ and $r$ have a common factor, in which case the number $r'$ returned by the continued fractions algorithm be a factor of $r$, and not $r$ itself. Fortunately, there are at least three ways around this problem, and

> A second method is to note that if $r'\neq r$, then $r'$ is guaranteed to be a factor of $r$, unless $s=0$, which possibility occurs with probability $1/r≤1/2$, and which can be
> discounted further by a few repetitions. Suppose we replace $a$ by $a'≡a^{r'}(\mod N)$. Then the order of $a'$ is $r/r'$. We can now repeat the algorithm, and try to compute the order of $a'$, which, if we succeed, allows us to compute the order of $a$, since $r=r'\times r/r'$. If we fail, then we obtain $r''$ which is a factor of $r/r''$ , and we now try to compute the order of $a''≡(a')^{r''}(\mod N )$. We iterate this procedure until we determine the order of $a$. At most $\log(r)=O(L)$ iterations are required since each repetition reduces the order of the current candidate $a''^{...}$ by a factor of at least two.

We have $s\in\{0,1,\cdots,r-1\}$ and I understand intuitively the fact that when $s$ and $r$ have a common factor then $r'$ returned by the continued fraction algorithm be a factor of r, and not $r$ itself.

> How do we say that it occurs with probability $1/r\le 1/2$, and it can be discounted further by a few repetitions?

If we obtain $r'\neq r$ then we obtain $a'=a^{r'}(\mod N)$ such that the order of $a'$ is $r/r'$. If we succeed this with the algorithm we can find the required $r=r'\times r/r'$. If we fail then we obtain $r''$ and we continue this by with $a^{''}=a^{r''}(\mod N)$ will we obtain the required $r$ which is the order of $a$.

Refer to [Page 231, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)